# How do I access my azure database data from my xamarin mobile app?

Tags: ios, visual-studio, azure, xamarin

I'm new to mobile app development, I've been tasked with making an app and so I'm now starting my voyage of discovery.  I am coding the app in Visual Studio 2015 with Xamarin using a Mac Book Pro as the client for testing,  all our data is stored in a database in our Azure portal.  The app I am making is for iOS.

I've read the documentation but I'm getting stuck in certain areas and I think it's down to not understanding what is needed based on conflicting documentation or my own failure to grasp the concepts outlined.

All I am looking to do at the moment is have my app grab data from my azure database and display it in a list/table.

The steps I have taken so far are:

1. I have created a very basic app within visual studio with a
   storyboard and a navigation item that points to a table view(where I'd like my data to be shown).
2. I created a Mobile App in my Azure account(as per documentation).
3. I have set the above mentioned mobile app to use my current existing database and supplied it with the username and password which all seems to be ok.

I am now at the point I need to get my app to talk to this mobile app and grab some data from my database.  The todo example is ok but it's not quite enough to get me up and running or more specifically it's not in quite the right context for my setup and I think it's causing confusion.

There seems to be a few ways to set the project up for data access but I'm not sure what would be best.

Can anyone assist?

Comment: You are on the correct path, do not have the mobile client connect to database directly, instead, call an API endpoint on your Mobile App that connects to the database and then returns results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are nearly there.

Instead of connecting directly to your database, you connect to your mobile apps API which then connects to your database, handles your request, and sends the data back to your app. You need to code this backend first so it is able to handle your requests. Take a look at this tutorial, it is really good : 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-dotnet-backend-how-to-use-server-sdk

Answer (score 0):

You will access your Azure Mobile App with the [Azure Mobile Client SDK](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client/) nuget package.

A complete guide to do this can be found here: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/web-services/consuming/azure/

There is also this podcast: https://blog.xamarin.com/podcast-building-connected-apps-with-azure-mobile-apps/